# How can i replace the manifest of an apk

Tags: android, runtime, apk, manifest, aapt

How can i replace an app's manifest file with my own?
I'm the developer of that app. So i have it's manifest file. But i want to change it's name or icon in manifest on runtime. Build it again, then install it again.

```
What i tried:
Step 1)
//Building an apk with my modified manifest file. (Only name or icon)

aapt package -f -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res/ -I android.jar -F MyProject.apk.unaligned

Step 2)

//Extracted aapt's generated apk's manifest. Replaced it with my target apk

Step 3)

jarsigner -storepass password -keystore pathToKeystore MyTargetApk.apk.unaligned keyname


Step 4)

zipalign 4 MyTargetApk.apk.unaligned MyTargetApk.apk
```

Everything above is done successfully. But When i try to install the app. I get "There was a problem parsing package."

 Why it gives this error? All i changed is the manifest file (and only name or icon in manifest)

**EDIT:**
*I compared the built apk's manifest with the original apk's manifest. Attributes are getting different values. For example: Theme should be `android:theme="@ref/0x7f070000"` in the built apk to work. But it's `android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0005"`*

 *It's looking for wrong resource in the resources.arsc file*

Comment: You need to sign the apk again after modifying it.

Comment: I've already done it on my step 3.

Comment: Try to see if only the name,icon and manifest are getting changed in the built apk. Maybe some other things are getting changed too?

Comment: I checked the built apk's manifest. some attributes are getting wrong resource id. for example, theme is android:theme="@ref/0x7f070000" while it should be android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0005".